# New questions not in "Newest Questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, stack-exchange

The "newest" tab on the [All Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) shows the same questions for the last 15 minutes. I can see the new questions on the [Top Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/) page.

Screenshot (yes, it's the first page):

[image: oldass questions]

Edit: same behaviour on mso, su, etc? It's ironic that nobody will see this question before this is fixed because of the bug this is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All fixed; in the process of deploying. And I have used the status-change on this very question to confirm that meta is working correctly now ;p

Normal service should be resumed in a few moments.