# Newest questions page - no new questions, though they exist

Tags: support, caching

This appears to be the same or similar issue as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101677/new-questions-not-in-newest-questions), though it is **not** fixed.

I had noticed it intermittently over the last week.

On a refresh of the `Newest Questions` page, questions that *were* there are gone, only older ones appear. Several refreshes later all is well in the world.

[image]

---

This just happened again - some questions were marked "3 minutes ago", a refresh and they are gone and I am only seeing "6 minutes ago", even though there are newer questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And at exactly the time it happened, we were building/deploying Stackoverflow. Whether it was the deploy, or simply the fact of picking up a different server (as they cycled), simply: for a brief moment, the cache was slightly older than you had before. This particular cache is self-managing, and when it notices that it is stale, it automatically kicks off a task to freshen itself in the background - but continues serving the marginally older data while it does so (so as not to delay requests).

Basically, I'm not sure we need to change anything here. It is a rare event, only exists for a few seconds (typically while we deploy), and is self-fixing within a few seconds.

Comment: Fair enough. It simply felt like a bug. I have seen this last for a minute or so.

Comment: @Oded what is the exact URL of the page you see this on? we also have top-level caching of the page contents, which might extend the duration a *little*. If you confirm the URL you are using, I'll see if we can make the refresh kill the page level cache

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: @Oded hmmm.... no explicit additional cache in there; I assume it was simply taking a few seconds to refresh itself (immediately after an app-pool reload, etc)

Comment: Possibly. Does this really explain seeing newer posts disappearing from the page? As you said, it does end up self-fixing, but sometimes the cache would be several minutes out of date (I have seen 9 minutes).

Comment: @Oded yes, if we are cycling the servers. That particular cache is [somewhat](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html) [complex](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector); we snapshot the data **literally** at random, between 5 and 10 minutes. When reloading from an empty app-domain, it loads the snapshot data, which could be as much as that out of date, yes. It will catch up soon, though.

Comment: Fair enough... Had my share of multiple cache levels issues. Looks like this is here to stays... Happy to see this [status-declined].

Comment: This just happened (assuming you are moving from rev 2012.6.11.2858 to rev 2012.6.11.2864) - though now the newest entries are a week old! I am seeing stuff from June 4th as new :( And I am not seeing a return to normalcy either.

Comment: @Oded on where? I just switched something over - it should fix itself momentarily. But: where are you seeing it?

Comment: SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest

Comment: @Oded k - switching it back... I need to give that switchover code some love :(

Comment: Ta. That looks better now...