# StackOverflow.com/Questions is Broken

Tags: bug, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Newest questions page - no new questions, though they exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117152/newest-questions-page-no-new-questions-though-they-exist)

The most recent question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions is from June 4th.
Refreshing the page has no effect.

I reproduced this in a Chrome Incognito window, but I haven't tried another ISP (I have FiOS).

Comment: Which tab are your looking at?

Comment: I can reproduce that, newest tab shows no questions younger than 4.6., active nothing with activity newer than 2 hours old. (SeaMonkey 2.9 on Linux).

Comment: [Newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) is showing this problem

Comment: We are aware, expect some hiccups here in the coming days as we make a major infrastructure shift behind the scenes.  *Do* keep reporting problems though, we do need to be aware of issues created along the way.

Comment: I wonder if it's similar to this report: [Old questions in the newest questions tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132929/old-questions-in-newest-questions-tab)

Comment: I can not reproduce this.

Comment: You all missed a perfectly good opportunity to try and convince SLaks that *today is June 4th* and that he is in fact crazy.