# Explosion of new questions after a network interruption

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

### Situation

Between 15 September 2012 and 16 September 2012, there was a [service interruption all across Stack Exchange](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5576/83694).  The newest questions and the top questions stopped updating, even though it was possible to ask new questions.

This means that all of the questions asked during the time that Stack Exchange was out didn't show up until the issue was fixed.

On Super User, 46 new questions were asked during the interruption.  I wonder what the number is for Stack Overflow, which has a much higher rate of new questions...

These questions did not get the exposure that they would have gotten under normal conditions, and the [attitude of answering questions is to be as fast as possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/188803).  Now, there's a slew of questions with zero upvotes and little attention, and they are being pushed down from the front page by new questions after the interruption ended.

**What action should original posters take to give their questions the chance of normal exposure?**

---

### Example

To test my concern, I asked a simple, short-answer question during the service interruption: [What is SandForce_Internal?](https://superuser.com/q/475635/83694)

Some users normally watching the front page might have had the answer, but it never got a chance to be at the top of the newest questions, and it may have lost its chance to getting enough attention for a quick answer.

Should I delete and re-ask the question?  It's a two day wait before I can put a bounty on it...

---

### Qualification

This question is not a too localized one-time event because this is [not the first time the front page stopped updating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101677/188803).

Should abnormal service happen again, what should posters do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is anything they can do. Not like we can just bump them all, because nothing would really happen. You'd still have questions off the front page that are fairly new.

For the larger sites, you could raise awareness of what happened and explain the situation of so many unviewed questions via chat or maybe on the per-site Meta, just pointing out that users should look farther back to find all the questions. But there are also lots of sites that weren't really affected at all by this. Some may not have even gained any new questions during the period.

Looking through Stack Overflow's pages, it doesn't appear users are having any problems browsing backwards a ways and finding more questions that can yet be answered.