# Some questions are not listed in 'newest questions' until long after posting?

Tags: bug

About an hour minutes ago I posted this question:

[ruby twitter gem: tactical anti-troll response-bot replies, but timeline doesn't show tweet replied to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284419/ruby-twitter-gem-tactical-anti-troll-response-bot-replies-but-timeline-doesnt)

However, although the question was immediately searchable on the 'twitter' site tag, and after an hour it is listed in the 'newest questions' section, I was monitoring 'newest questions' at the time and the question did not appear.

This question seems to list the same bug:

[New questions not in "Newest Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101677/new-questions-not-in-newest-questions)

But lists it as fixed, so I guess this one is something different? Particularly as the original askers' question didn't seem to appear in the timeline at all... though at the same time he didn't wait an hour, so perhaps it appeared after his question was asked...

Comment: What do you mean by "monitoring"? Refreshing? How do you know that it never appeared rather than you just missing it? The current top 50 newest questions on SO are only 9 minutes old...

Comment: Yes, I mean refreshing. I was watching other questions move down the list and mine did not appear on the first page. I refreshed until after it had been filled with other questions. I was constantly refreshing because the number of views seemed lower than usual. It would not have been possible to miss its appearance on the first page.

Comment: Btw, I think it would be quickly appeared on main page and active tab.